# How to record audio and then store the record audio file in database in laravel project

Tags: javascript, laravel, audio, model-view-controller, html5-audio

audio file is recording and also download but not store in databse.

I am trying multiple ways to store audio file but nothing is succeeded.

Once you've recorded the audio and obtained a Blob object, then how to submitt the audio without ajax

Comment: With a form maybe ? I do not understand your question very well.

Comment: Yes with a form

Comment: why don't you just save the audio path in the db?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.